# What is a DFA that accepts strings in (a+b)* where number of a's are even and there are at least 2 b's?

Tags: automata

I understand that possible strings for this language is basically any combo of a's and b's, n times, with a's being even and at least 2 b's.

For the even a's I'm thinking of a DFA with 2 states and the initial state being accepting, that loops back to initial state when a is even. However when I mix this with the DFA that takes in 2 b's there is always a case where my DFA does not work, and accepts strings like "abb".

Any input on this?

Comment: Informally, a state in a DFA is a "memory note".  So there are two things you could have for the number of $a$s: even or odd.  To count the $b$s there are three relevant possibilities: $0$; $1$; at least $2$.  You will (probably) need to consider all possible combinations of these: so one state would be "even number of $a$s and at least $2$ $b$s".  Write down all (how many?) states and work out how to get from one to another.  Good luck!